# Create a column 'geometry' of points with longitude and latitude data given in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

I have loaded a .csv data into a pandas DataFrame and want to create a column named 'geometry' which will be made up of the shapely points from the lat and lon as given in the data. The data is below

[image: the .csv data loaded; made up of lat, lon, timestamp and userid.]

I therefore would want to create a Shapely point on each row, based on columns 'lon' and 'lat' and zip lon and lat columns and create the points using a for-loop (loop over the zipped object), OR
use the apply method to apply the shapely Point constructor on each row.

This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

from shapely.geometry import Point

fp = 'C:/Users/pku/Desktop/data/lat_lon.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(fp)

data.head()

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

datafram['geometry'] = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(data.lon, data.lat)] 

print(data['geometry'].head())
```

I had a bunch of errors...the last one being.

[image: the end of the error]

Comment: You set `datafram['geometry'] ` not `data['geometry']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you read a csv file with Pandas the result is a Pandas DataFrame, therefore why create a new DataFrame: `dataframe = pd.DataFrame()` ?

```
data = pd.read_csv("lat_long.csv")
list(data.columns)
['lat', 'lon']
type(data)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
data.head()
     lat       lon
0  41.389474  2.156421
1  41.383093  2.181116
2  41.373258  2.159358
3  41.385252  2.168779
4  41.390692  2.148911
```

Now

You can use List Comprehension

```
data['geometry'] = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(data.lon, data.lat)] 
data.head()
     lat       lon                    geometry
0  41.389474  2.156421  POINT (2.156421 41.389474)
1  41.383093  2.181116  POINT (2.181116 41.383093)
2  41.373258  2.159358  POINT (2.159358 41.373258)
3  41.385252  2.168779  POINT (2.168779 41.385252)
4  41.390692  2.148911  POINT (2.148911 41.390692)
```

You can use the apply command

```
data['geometry2'] = data.apply(lambda row:Point(row['lon'],row['lat']), axis=1)
data.head()
     lat       lon                    geometry                   geometry2
0  41.389474  2.156421  POINT (2.156421 41.389474)  POINT (2.156421 41.389474)
1  41.383093  2.181116  POINT (2.181116 41.383093)  POINT (2.181116 41.383093)
2  41.373258  2.159358  POINT (2.159358 41.373258)  POINT (2.159358 41.373258)
3  41.385252  2.168779  POINT (2.168779 41.385252)  POINT (2.168779 41.385252)
4  41.390692  2.148911  POINT (2.148911 41.390692)  POINT (2.148911 41.390692)
```

You can also use [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/index.html) ([From CSV to GeoDataFrame in two lines](https://anitagraser.com/2019/01/23/from-csv-to-geodataframe-in-two-lines/))

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = pd.read_csv("lat_long.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data.lon, data.lat) 
gdf.head()
     lat       lon                  geometry
0  41.389474  2.156421  POINT (2.15642 41.38947)
1  41.383093  2.181116  POINT (2.18112 41.38309)
2  41.373258  2.159358  POINT (2.15936 41.37326)
3  41.385252  2.168779  POINT (2.16878 41.38525)
4  41.390692  2.148911  POINT (2.14891 41.39069)
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked fine. Happy to be on this platform. Thanks, families.

Comment: If this answer is acceptable to you, you must close the question by accepting the answer please.